# Excel Data Validation - How to validate a cell using IF function after a Yes/No droplist menu?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, if-statement, drop-down-menu

The issue is quite simple, and I have seen that it is maybe possible to do it using VBA, but I am quite confident it is also possible to do using just data validation.

I have a Yes/No dropdown list in Column A, and I would like to display "0" if "yes", or be able to insert the number (e.g. 3200) if "no", in Column B.

```
A       B
yes     0
No      3200 (or any other number)
yes     0
```

I tried customizing data validation using IF function:

```
=IF($A1="Yes", "0", "")
```

but in that way I cannot insert a number on the cell.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF($A2="Yes",0,AND($B2>0,$B2<99999))
```

Put the formula above in data validation and it should work. Make sure that the whole column B is selected while defining the formula

Comment: Hi Shazu, thank you for replying me, but unfortunately it is not what I need. "3200" was an example to say "I need to insert a number there". Moreover, I don't need a formula on cells under column B, but something like Data Validation > Custom > Formula.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I have updated my answer accordingly. You only need to come up with a maximum possible number in B column for the case when you have a "No" in the A column. I have currently defined 99999 as the maximum possible number. You can obviously change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. It works and I got the logic. Do you think there would be any chance to also display "0" when is "Yes"?

Comment: Do you mean automatically display 0 for all cases where the corresponding cell in column A has "Yes" in it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be really perfect in that case.

Comment: Ok. The answer depends on how your spreadsheet is going to be filled up. If values in column A will remain unchanged, you could enter the formula =if(A2="Yes", 0, "") in B1 and drag it down. Afterwards, you could enter the formula in the answer above in data validation and then manually enter the numbers you want in B next to the "No" values in A. If, however, the values in A are dynamic, I can only think of a vba solution.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same and you confirmed it. Being dynamic the only solution would be on VBA. It was not a big deal by the way, the formula on data validation that you provided me works perfectly as well. Thank you once more!